# How to select Nth element in XPath with multilevel nesting

Tags: xpath, selector, css-selectors

We can use :position() in xpath to retreive nth element in simple HTML block like this:

```
<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
<li>third</li>
</ul>
```

We can query element by `//li[position()=2]` but this won't work in this situation:

```
<ul>
<b><li>first</li></b>
<b><li>second</li></b>
<b><li>third</li></b>
</ul>
```

And we have to use `//b[position()=2]/li`.

**The problems is that I want to create a XPath rule for nth-element for my selenium test, which will no be tight coupled with decoarational tags**. I need a XPath that will work even when mu nth-elements will be decorated with additional tags.

I know that for testing purposes I can change backend logic to provide additional testing handles in html like data-* attributes, but suppose that I can't change code of app under test.

So, I'm searching for XPath query like: **"Give me third `<li>` element, wherever it lays in specified page (or page block) even if it is multiply nested"**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that `[position()=3]` can be shorthened to `[3]`. The answer to your question then is

```
(//li)[3]
```

The position is related to the nodelist returned by the parentheses.

Comment: is it could be `[-1]` ?

Comment: @BudiMulyo: No, but you can use `[last()]`.

Comment: `"name 'last' is not defined"`

Comment: @BudiMulyo: What implementation of XPath are you using? Works for me. `(//li)[last()]`

Comment: I'm using python, sample works code : `chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'tablGroupsO_paginate']/ul/li[8]")`

Comment: @BudiMulyo: Without seeing the HTML that corresponds to the expression, I can't help you much. If you want the last `li`, just `.../ul/li[last()]` should work.